# Traces of TCM Search Indexer

Tags: web8, search-engine

I'm trying to obtain traces of the TCM Search Indexer service, with the new **Content Manager tracing tool** but with no success.

I'm executing:

```
Start-TcmTracing -TraceFile C:\tridion\log\indexer.log -ProcessNames TcmSearchIndexer
```

to start tracing the service, the command returns me the Id of the tracing process, but no traces appear from that service.

If no `-ProcessName` is entered, then I can see traces of `w3wp`, `TcmServiceHost`, etc. but nothing from `Search Indexer`.

Is there any other modification needed to extract those traces? or simply the service is not working as expected?

Comment: Not that this helps you... but I have the same results on an 8.5 box, so I guess indeed tracing is not enabled for this process?

Answer (score 3):

we were just working a support ticket which requested us to do this to enable tracing for the search indexer. it doesn't log to a file, but to the screen.

1. Stop the SDL Web Content Manager Search Indexer service
2. Drop out to command prompt as administrator and navigate to ..sdlweb\bin
3. Type: TcmSearchIndexer.exe -d

Comment: yeah, I figured out how to put the search indexer in debug mode with a command console, puting the parameter "-debug" as the TcmPublisher.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Start-TcmTracing collects trace messages marked as Public, Extension or External. It just happened that SearchIndexer in default setup doesn't execute any of such code. In order to see trace messages from indexer, set -TraceKeywords to 'All' (or 'Internal').